# Calling a Stored Procedure Using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am not able to set the server output to `ON`, while running the Java code. But I am able to connect to Oracle SQL database.

Getting below error:

> ****java.lang.NullPointerException DB Connected successfully java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00922: missing or invalid
>   option****

Please suggest me a solution.

Code:

```
ResultSet rs= DS_DB.getResultSet("set serveroutput on");
DS_DB.connectDatabase();

String command = "{call sfmd.getNativeIdsForXID('EDDAC')}";
CallableStatement cstmt = connection.prepareCall(command);
cstmt.execute();
System.out.println("Cstmt :"+command);'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what your trying to do here.

If your looking for the result set, Oracle doesn't return result sets, you need to define one of your parameters as an output parameter of type SYS_REFCURSOR.

```
String command = "{call sfmd.getNativeIdsForXID(?,?)}";
CallableStatement cstmt = connection.prepareCall(command);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, ORACLE_CURSOR_TYPE);
cstmt.setObject(2, 'EDDAC');
cstmt.execute();

ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) cstmt.getObject(1);
```

In your Stored Procedure, define the output parameter

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "getNativeIdsForXID" (
    NativeIdsCursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR, 
    P_XID VARCHAR(20)) IS

  open NativeIdsCursor for 
  SELECT ID from SomeTable where XID = P_XID;

END "getNativeIdsForXID";
```

You can also get output if you use the dbms_output package in your stored procedure.

Here's a couple of utilities to do that.  You enable the dbms output, then execute your procedure like you normally would, then you can print the output afterward.

```
    public static void enableDBMSOutput(DBConnection conn, int buffer_size) {

        try {

            String SQLString = null;

            if (buffer_size > 0)
                SQLString = "sys.dbms_output.enable(?)";
            else
                //SQLString = "{call sys.dbms_output.enable(buffer_size => NULL) }"; // Unlimited
                SQLString = "sys.dbms_output.enable(buffer_size => NULL)"; // Unlimited

            CallableStatement stmt = conn.getCallableStatement(true, SQLString);

            if (buffer_size > 0)
                stmt.setInt(1,buffer_size);

            stmt.execute();

            System.out.println("DBMS_OUTPUT has been Enabled!");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem occurred enabling dbms_output: " + e.toString());
        }
    }


    public static void disableDBMSOutput(DBConnection conn) {

        try {

            String SQLString = "sys.dbms_output.disable()";

            CallableStatement stmt = conn.getCallableStatement(true, SQLString);

            stmt.execute();

            System.out.println("DBMS_OUTPUT has been Disabled!");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem occurred disabling dbms_output: " + e.toString());
        }
    }


    public static void printDBMSOutput(DBConnection conn) {

        try {
            String SQLString = "sys.dbms_output.get_line(?,?)";

            CallableStatement stmt = conn.getCallableStatement(true, SQLString);

            stmt.registerOutParameter(1,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(2,java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);

            int status = 0;
            String output = null;

            do {
                stmt.execute();
                output = stmt.getString(1);
                status = stmt.getInt(2);

                if (null != output)
                    System.out.println("dbms_output: " + output);

            } while (status == 0);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problem occurred during print_dbms_output: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    public static String [] getDBMSOutput(DBConnection conn) {

        try {
            String SQLString = "{call sys.dbms_output.get_line(?,?)}";

            CallableStatement stmt = conn.getCallableStatement(true, SQLString);

            stmt.registerOutParameter(1,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(2,java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);

            int status = 0;
            String output = null;
            ArrayList <String> dbmsOutput = new ArrayList<String>();
            do {
                stmt.execute();
                output = stmt.getString(1);
                status = stmt.getInt(2);

                if (null != output)
                    dbmsOutput.add(output);

            } while (status == 0);

            return (String [])dbmsOutput.toArray();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problem occurred during print_dbms_output: " + e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public CallableStatement getCallableStatement(boolean isProcedure, String sqlString){
    try {
        if (isProcedure) {
            String query = "{ call " + sqlString + " }";

            return dbConn.prepareCall(query);
        } else
            return dbConn.prepareCall(sqlString);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike,I am getting Import Issue with DBConnection cannot be resolved to a type for public static void enableDBMSOutput(DBConnection conn, int buffer_size)

Comment: @BhaskarReddy DBConnection is a class I created, you can change it to Connection (java.sql)

Comment: @BhaskarReddy the getCallableStatement basically does a conn.prepareCall(SqlString)

Comment: @BhaskarReddy Added the getCallableStatement code, but I have a Connection wrapped in a larger functional class (DBConnection), so you need to take the code and make it your own, but all the components are there on what you need to do, it won't just run with a cut/paste, although it's not that far off.  The static functions were actually part of a utility class (separate from DBConnection) called JDBCUtils.  getCallableStatement was part of my DBConnection class.

Answer (score 0):

`set serveroutput on` is a SQL*plus command and not available in JDBC driver. JDBC driver is not dbms_output aware. Tom Kyte's site has a nice explanation and possible solution. https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:45027262935845

Comment: This isn't entirely true, you can capture Oracle Output from the dbms_output package.  I'll post it as another answer.

Comment: @Mike JDBC does not have an interface to natively capture dbms_output. In the link I provided a similar solution to what you are suggesting.Using the PL/SQL  dbms_output.get_line package.